# Failure in invoking method through instance

Tags: python, class, instance, attributeerror, method-invocation

I have this absolutely preposterous error which I have completely given up on. Here is my code:

```
class SaveGame:
    def __init__ (self):
      self.stats ={'strength':player.strength, 'dexterity':player.dexterity, 'inventory':player.inventory, 'read-inventory':player._inventory, 'equipped weapons':player.equippedweapons, 'Consumable supply':procs.consum, 'Health':procs.health, 'poisoned?':procs.poison, 'storypointe':storypointe}

    def save (self):
        try:
            with open (savefile, 'wb') as savebin:
                pickle.dump (self.stats, savefile)
        except KeyError:
            print "Unable to load game"
            sys.exit (0)

    def load (self):
        pickle.load (savefile)
```

Now, when I go to the implementation....:

```
startgame = raw_input ("Would you like to load your game or start a new one\n>>> ")

if startgame in ['load game', 'load my game', 'Load my game', 'Load game', 'load', 'Load']:
    loadedgame = SaveGame ()
    loadedgame.load ()
```

I get this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import ModRpg
  File "C:\Users\Sammu\The Folder\ModRpg.py", line 317, in <module>
    loadedgame.load ()
  AttributeError: SaveGame instance has no attribute 'load'
```

Comment: Wow, hold back on the endless code there, buddy. Could you simplify that to your exact problem? And take a look at [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186) for editing help on your code blocks.

Comment: And as you have been in the answer the `AttributeError: SaveGame instance has no attribute 'load'` is because of bad indentation.  If you ask for comments/help you should read the comments/suggestions and actually act on it.

Answer (score 4):

Your indentation is goofed, with tabs and spaces mixed. Use `python -tt` to verify.

Comment: By "not helping" do you mean that I'm wrong, or that you don't like what I wrote?

Comment: He is helping, it looks like because of your bad indenting, the load() method is actually nested in the save() method, hence the AttributeError.